# How can i get the 3 textview from recyclerview and pass it to dialogbox

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Im new to android programming so can you provide me the right code.
this is my code. the data is from sqlite. my problem is . How can i get the 3 textview from recyclerview and pass it to dialogbox when clicked? i finally made dialogbox but i can get only the position of the item i want to get all of the three textview data. please help me.

FragmentMeal.java

```
package inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.fragments;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.R;
import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.database.DatabaseHelper;
import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.adapters.VivzAdapter;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentMeal#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentMeal extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private VivzAdapter adapter;


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;



    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentMeal.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentMeal newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentMeal fragment = new FragmentMeal();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentMeal() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meal, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealList);
        adapter = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),db.getMealData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

            @Override


            public void onClick(View view, int postion) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.show();

                final EditText editText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_pin);
                Button submitButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
                Button cancelButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

                submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pin submitted is : " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });


                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLongClick" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }));

        return view;
    }

    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;
        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){
            Log.d("VIVZ", "constructor invoked ");
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d("VIVZ","onSingleTapUp " + e);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null){

                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));

                    }
                    Log.d("VIVZ", "onLongPress " + e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){

                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));

            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("VIVZ","onTouchEvent "+ e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    public static interface ClickListener {

        public void onClick(View arg1, int arg2);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    }

}
```

VivzAdapter.java

```
package inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.adapters;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.R;
import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.fragments.FragmentMeal;
import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.pojo.Contact;
import inncharge.poy.madrigal.innchargev1.pojo.Information;

/**
 * Created by Madrigal on 7/18/2015.
 */
public class VivzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VivzAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Contact> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public VivzAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> data){

        this.context=context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;

    }

    public void delete(int position){
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        Log.d("VIVZ","onCreateHolder called ");
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contact current = data.get(position);
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onBindViewHolder called " + position);
        holder.itemId.setText(String.valueOf(current.getId()));
        holder.title.setText(current.getName());
        holder.email.setText(current.getEmail());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView title;
        public TextView email;
        public TextView itemId;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextName);
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextUname);
            itemId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slidenerd makes some great videos, he helped me a lot as well when I started.

You might want to reconsider what you're trying to do and approach it differently... Why would you want to pass 3 textview from your UI into a dialog?
This is going to be painful.

Seems like you're going to have to extend DialogFragment (i'm assuming that's what you're using for a dialog, maybe an alert?). Create a static factory method inside the DialogFragment like this...

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static tv1, tv2, tv3;

    public static MyDialog newInstance(TextView tv1, TextView tv2, TextView tv3){
       MyDialog.tv1 = tv1;
       MyDialog.tv2 = tv2;
       MyDialog.tv3 = tv3;
       return new MyDialog();
    }
}
```

Once you have this complete, create this dialog fragment inside that onClick method in the ViewHolder class. Instantiate the DialogFragment by doing this...

```
MyDialog.newInstance(title,email,itemId).show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog_tag");
```

Like i said before, it's seems sloppy and is probably error prone. There may be a better way of doing this but this is all I can think of off the top of my head. Let me know how it works out for you.. or perhaps revise your question so we can better help you reach a better solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: thankyou hitch, i have problem getFragmentManager() it says that i cannot resolve this.

Comment: try this : MyDialog.newInstance(title, email, itemId).show( ( (Activity) context ).getFragmentManager(), "dialog_tag");

Comment: pptang i try your code it works. but noting happen. the dialog does not pops out.

Comment: Did you finish making the dialog fragment? You need to override onCreateView(); and all the other relevant methods.